# Field type 'whatever' is an abstract class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

Is there any way to get Clang to give me a more useful message than "Field type 'whatever' is an abstract class" when I try to instantiate a subclass of an abstract class, and fail to override a pure virtual method in a subclass? Information such as the name of the method(s) that I forgot to override would save some time!

Comment: If not, you could always add it to clang yourself!

Comment: What version of clang are you using? I'm getting a nice note using 3.4 "test.cpp:6:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'bar' in 'derived'"

Comment: Whatever is in XCode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: ... which according to wikipedia is (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)